# Onchange not working properly with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**In my view I have**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsBasket, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group" id="IsBasket">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IsBasket, ViewBag.RefAssetType as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="SingleStock" class="hide">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReferenceAsset, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReferenceAsset, ViewBag.RefAssetList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Basket" class="hide">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayoutCurrency, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PayoutCurrency, ViewBag.CurrencyList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**my script**

```
<script>

        $('#IsBasket').on('change',function()
        {
            if ($(this).val()== true)
            {
                $('#SingleStock').addClass('hide');
                $('#Basket').removeClass('hide');
            }
            if ($(this).val() == false)
            {
                $('#Basket').addClass('hide');
                $('#SingleStock').removeClass('hide');
            }
        })

</script>
```

**The selection list for RefAssetType is defined here**

```
Dictionary<bool, string> RefAssetTypeDictonary = new Dictionary<bool, string>
            {

                {false, "Single Stock"},
                {true, "Basket"},
            };

ViewBag.RefAssetType = new SelectList(RefAssetTypeDictonary, "Key", "Value");
```

what I want to have ultimately is if the user selects "Basket" from id="IsBasket" then the input id=Basket will show up. If it's SingleStock, then the input id=SingleStock part will show up. But the change is not working..

I hope someone can help on this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're attaching an onchange handler to the div that contains your dropdown menu. When the value of the dropdown changes, that doesn't mean the container div changes. It should work if you change your jQuery selector to use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
$('#IsBasket').find('select').on('change',function() {
    // ...
});
```

With this selector, you're attaching the onchange handler to any HTML select elements contained in the div with ID `#IsBasket`.

Comment: thanks.. but its not working. neither of the basket or singlestock section shows up

Comment: What does the HTML code that's generated by your template look like? I was assuming it would render a select element

Comment: put an alert or console.log statement inside the change handler function, to see if it fires

Comment: I put alert within the if. It indicates only the second if got hit. Even I selected basket, it didnt pass true.